# R + shiny + plotly: ggplotly moves the legend to the right

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

Please have a look at the reprex at the end of the post.
Essentially, I create a very simple ggplot2 visualization inside shiny.
When I call ggplotly on it in order to get a plotly interactive visualization, the plot legend which was at the top of the plot, gets shifted to the right.
Any idea about how to fix that?

Many thanks!

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


df <- tibble(x=seq(20), y=seq(20), type=c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10)))


ui <- fluidPage(

mainPanel(
    plotOutput("myplot" ),
    plotlyOutput("myplot2" )
    
    )
    
)



server <- function(input, output) {

myplot <- reactive({
    
gpl1 <- df%>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill=type)) +
    geom_col()+
    theme(legend.position="top")+
    xlab("x")+
    ylab("y")+
    labs(title = NULL)

gpl1



})



myplot2 <- reactive({
    
gpl2 <- df%>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill=type)) +
    geom_col()+
    theme(legend.position="top")+
    xlab("x")+
    ylab("y")+
    labs(title = NULL)

ggplotly(gpl2)




})

    
    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
        myplot()
        
    })

    output$myplot2 <- renderPlotly({
        myplot2()
        
    })

    
    
}




shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2021-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add some plotly grammar to fix it.

`layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h', x = 0.45, y = 1.1))`

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(x=seq(20), y=seq(20), type=c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("myplot" ),
    plotlyOutput("myplot2" )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  myplot <- reactive({
    gpl1 <- df%>%
      ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill=type)) +
      geom_col()+
      theme(legend.position="top")+
      xlab("x")+
      ylab("y")+
      labs(title = NULL)
    gpl1
  })
  
  myplot2 <- reactive({
    gpl2 <- df%>%
      ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill=type)) +
      geom_col()+
      theme(legend.position="top")+
      xlab("x")+
      ylab("y")+
      labs(title = NULL)
    ggplotly(gpl2) %>% 
      layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h', x = 0.45, y = 1.1))
  })
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    myplot()
  })
  output$myplot2 <- renderPlotly({
    myplot2()
  })
}
  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: It is not working in my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69484878/how-to-fix-altering-axis-problem-in-ggplotly-in-r#  . I have tried `ggplotly(pp) %>% layout(xaxis = list(side = "top"), legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.4, y = 0.2))` which did not change the legend position.