# How to change legend position in ggplotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

The below code generates two plots using `ggplot` and `ggplotly`. Despite of using the `layout()` to ggplotly the legend is still at the right side. The legend is required to be at the bottom. Could anyone help to move the legend to bottom in the ggplotly? I have tried the solution at [R + shiny + plotly: ggplotly moves the legend to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306154/r-shiny-plotly-ggplotly-moves-the-legend-to-the-right) and is not working here. Can someone help if im missing the obvious.

```
measure<-c("MSAT","MSAT","GPA","MSAT","MSAT","GPA","GPA","GPA")
score<-c(500, 490, 2.9, 759, 550, 1.2, 3.1, 3.2)
data<-data.frame(measure,score)


ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("myplot" ),
    plotlyOutput("myplot2" )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  myplot <- reactive({
    gpl1 <- ggplot(data,aes(y=reorder(measure, score),x=score,fill=score)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity")+
      theme(legend.position="bottom")+
      xlab("x")+
      ylab("y")+
      labs(title = NULL)
    gpl1
  })
  
  myplot2 <- reactive({
    gpl2 <- ggplot(data,aes(y=reorder(measure, score),x=score,fill=score)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +
      theme(legend.position="bottom")+
      xlab("x")+
      ylab("y")+
      labs(title = NULL)
    ggplotly(gpl2) %>% 
      layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h', x = 0.45, y = 1.1))
  })
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    myplot()
  })
  output$myplot2 <- renderPlotly({
    myplot2()
  })
}
  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The reason the top plot is structured that way is because of the themes you chose.

Comment: i need to render this plot in a shiny app as interactive plot `renderplotly` to `plotlyOutput` . So i am converting to `ggplotly(p)`

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my comment. I didn't notice that you were saying `ggplotly` and not `ggplot`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R + shiny + plotly: ggplotly moves the legend to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306154/r-shiny-plotly-ggplotly-moves-the-legend-to-the-right)

Comment: `ggplotly(pp) %>% layout(xaxis = list(side = "top"),legend = list(side="bottom"))` the axis is moved to top but the legend is still on the right. Also tried `ggplotly(pp) %>% layout(xaxis = list(side = "top"), legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.4, y = 0.2))` which also did not change the legend position.

Comment: You are commenting here and on the other post but just not providing some reproducible code, we can't help you.

Comment: Original post is updated with reproducible code.

Comment: Any hints now with the reproducible code?

Comment: I have tried installing older versions of both `plotly` and `ggplot2` (which haven't been updated since that other answer anyway, but thought I'd try).  Very confused how this worked in September (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69306461/9096420), but not now (less than two months later).

Answer (score 3):

Okay this isn't a full answer, but it is a start that might help someone else pinpoint the problem, and it is too long to fit into a comment. It is possible it is worth opening up an issue, although I am not sure where (i.e. within what package) the problem lies.

I re-ran the code from [R + shiny + plotly: ggplotly moves the legend to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306154/r-shiny-plotly-ggplotly-moves-the-legend-to-the-right) and it works as it should, but for some reason yours doesn't. The only difference is that your `fill` is continuous, whereas the fill in that one is categorical.

If you add a categorical group here for score:

```
measure<-c("MSAT","MSAT","GPA","MSAT","MSAT","GPA","GPA","GPA")
score<-c(500, 490, 2.9, 759, 550, 1.2, 3.1, 3.2)
data<-data.frame(measure,score,score.f=as.factor(score))
```

Then the code you have works. You need to modify the `gpl2` object with `fill=score.f` (instead of `fill=score`), and also need to change the y value in the layout to get the legend to the bottom:

```
ggplotly(gpl2) %>% 
            layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h', x = 0.45, y = -.07))
```

[image]

Yet, as soon as you change the fill group to a continuous

```
score<-c(500, 490, 2.9, 759, 550, 1.2, 3.1, 3.2)
data<-data.frame(measure,score,score.f=score)
```

The legend goes back to being on the right:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As @ismirsehregal mentioned plotly does not yet support the horizontal colorbar, and the colorbar is present to support the continuous-valued fill attribute. So until plotly supports that orientation an alternative solution might serve temporarily: change the fill from continuous value to a discrete value.  Here is the reactive using (a) a cut for the discrete values, and (b) plotly anchors for the bottom legend.

```
myplot2 <- reactive({
  gpl2 <- ggplot(data,aes(y=reorder(measure, score),
                          x=score,
                          fill=cut(score, breaks=seq(0,800,100)))) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +
      labs(x='x',y='y',title=NULL,fill='Score') +
      theme(legend.position = 'bottom') +
      # scale_fill_stepsn(colours = terrain.colors(10),n.breaks=10)
      scale_fill_viridis_d()

    ggplotly(gpl2) %>%
      plotly::layout(legend=list(x=0, 
                                 xanchor='left',
                                 yanchor='bottom',
                                 orientation='h'))    
})
```

[image: plotly bottom legend]

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, that you are dealing with a **colorbar** not a legend.

Currently plotly [does not offer horizontal colorbars](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1244).

Also changing the position of a colorbar seems to be buggy in the ggplotly context:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

measure<-c("MSAT","MSAT","GPA","MSAT","MSAT","GPA","GPA","GPA")
score<-c(500, 490, 2.9, 759, 550, 1.2, 3.1, 3.2)
data<-data.frame(measure,score)


ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("myplot" ),
    plotlyOutput("myplot2" )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  myplot <- reactive({
    gpl1 <- ggplot(data,aes(y=reorder(measure, score),x=score,fill=score)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity")+
      theme(legend.position="bottom")+
      xlab("x")+
      ylab("y")+
      labs(title = NULL)
    gpl1
  })
  
  myplot2 <- reactive({
    fig <- ggplotly(myplot())
    fig <- style(fig, marker = list(colorbar = list(xanchor = "center", yanchor = "center", x = 0.5, y = -1, title = "test")), traces = NULL) # try traces = 1 or 1:2
    # browser()
    # plotly_json(fig)
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    myplot()
  })
  
  output$myplot2 <- renderPlotly({
    myplot2()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Accordingly, for now I'd recommend not to modify the colorbar and use the defaults.